# Stretch background image width but crop height

Tags: html, css, background

How do you make a background `img` that would:

1. Stretch across the window horizontally
2. Have a fixed height
3. Crop height when it's bigger than the content's height (do not shrink)

Currently I have this code that implements #1 and #2 but I can't seem to make it do #3:

```
<img class="background" src="images/page-background.png"/>

html {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I tried moving the `img` inside a `div` with `overflow: hidden` but that didn't work for some reason:

```
<div class="background-wrap">
    <img class="background" src="images/page-background.png"/>
</div>

.background-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

How would you do this properly in CSS / HTML (without JavaScript)?

Comment: have a look to this blog https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys, it turns out I completely forgot to remove a duplicate background `<img>` that I left after splitting my HTML in multiple files (actually PHP files but that's irrelevant).

For the sake of future reference, the following worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
       <div class="background-wrap">
           <img class="background" src="images/page-background.png"/>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>

html {
    position: relative;
}

.background-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2800px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a css background-image on a div like so:

```
.background-wrap {
 background: url(images/page-background.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 500px;
}
```

The background-size specifying that;
Stretch 100% across the window horizontally, and have a 500px fixed height (change this to auto if you want the image height to scale in proportion to the width).